# В Array list необходимо переписать содержимое

Tags: java, массивы

Имеется массив в ячейке которого записано значения в виде:

```
ArrayList list= new Array list();
String str="CQUAD4         2       1       3       8       9       2270.0000"
list.add(str);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста способ как перезаписать значения(сдвинуть нужные значения на 1 позицию) в ячейки list  например что бы при запросе list.get (0 )получилось следующие:

```
CQUAD4         2       1       8       9       2       3270.0000
```

Длина ячейки 64.
Массив сделан потому что таких строчек будет много. Я их считываю с txt файла. В примере я написал одну так как не имеет разницы их количество. В каждой ячейки мне нужно будет сделать манипуляции с перебором. В строке записана форма записи где под каждый столбец выделяется место в размере 8 символов. Начиная с 4 столбца по 7 нужно их переписать( 4 станет 5, 5-6,6-7,7-1)

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Хоть форматируйте правильно, может, что-то прояснится

Comment: Я исправил вопрос и попытался расписать его

Comment: Всё ещё не понятно. Вам надо изменить как-то строку, которую вы привели в вопросе? Если да - то не понятно при чём тут массив. И почему строки приведённые отличаются. Попробуйте ещё раз поправить вопрос так, чтобы можно было однозначно понять суть задачи.

Comment: Я снова исправил вопрос

Comment: Какие данные вы обрабатываете? У вас в txt загнана таблица, на кодировку каждой из строк отведено определенное количество символов?
И вам нужно распарсить строку на колонки и проводить манипуляции с данными из колонок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Разбить строку на колонки по 8 символов можно при помощи `String::split` с регуляркой вида `(?<=\G.{8})`, в результате получится массив строк.
2. Преобразовать массив в список строк следует при помощи `Arrays.asList`, так как полученный список будет использовать исходный массив и все изменения в списке (подсписки / сдвиги) будут отображаться и в массиве.
3. Поскольку необходимо сдвигать данные в колонках с индексами от 3 до 7 (индексы массивов/списков начинаются с 0), следует получить подсписок при помощи [`List::subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)
4. Сдвинуть элементы подсписка следует при помощи [`Collections::rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-), для сдвига *влево* на 1 следует использовать расстояние `-1`
5. Можно убедиться в том, что данные изменения отобразились на списке/массиве.
6. Для "восстановления" строки из изменённого массива можно воcпользоваться методом [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Образец кода в виде функции:

```java
public static String transform(String str) {
    // 1) получаем массив колонок шириной 8 символов
    String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G.{8})");
    // 2) конвертируем массив в список
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
    // 3) берём подсписок нужных колонок
    List<String> sub = list.subList(3, 7);
    // 4) и сдвигаем его на 1 колонку влево
    Collections.rotate(sub, -1);
    // 5) вывод массива, чтобы убедиться в корректности сдвига (закомментирован)
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // 6) возврат строки
    return String.join("", arr);
}
// ...
// тест
String str = "CQUAD4         1       2       3       4       5       6270.0000";
System.out.println("было:  " + str);
System.out.println("стало: " + transform(str));
```

```
было:  CQUAD4         1       2       3       4       5       6270.0000
стало: CQUAD4         1       2       4       5       6       3270.0000
```